# Python: naming of boolean/flag class attributes

Tags: python, coding-style

Coding style question: What is the recommended way of naming flag class attributes, i.e. attributes being `True` or `False`. Styles I can think of are:

1. `class MyClass:
       def my_method(self):
           self.request = False`
2. `class MyClass:
       def my_method(self):
           self.is_request = False`
3. `class MyClass:
       def my_method(self):
           self.request_flag = False`

PEP8 does not seem to give a firm recommendation. Is there a canonical way of doing this?

Comment: I've always wondered about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that booleans are mostly used in coditions, the second way seems most appropriate.

```
o = MyClass()
...
if o.is_request: # very intuitive
    # it's a request
```